# In RCT settings, are randomization inference p-values always greater than OLS p-values?

Tags: econometrics, experimental-economics, randomized-experiment

I was wondering if there's a proven/known relationship between RI p-values and OLS p-values in RCT settings, where treatment is completely random. [Alwyn Young's paper](https://personal.lse.ac.uk/YoungA/ChannellingFisherQJE.pdf)<sup>1</sup> shows many examples of OLS p-values that were smaller than RI p-values, but is this a coincidence or broadly more true?

And if RI p-values can be smaller than OLS p-values, what would be the reason for that? Young argues that high leverage points cause OLS standard errors/p-values to become smaller than they should be, so is there a similar explanation for why OLS errors/p-values would be too large compared to RI?

Thank you!

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Young, Alwyn. "Channeling fisher: Randomization tests and the statistical insignificance of seemingly significant experimental results." *The quarterly journal of economics* 134, no. 2 (2019): 557-598.</sub>

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a link or a more informative citation of the paper you are referring to.

Comment: Adding that now, thank you for flagging!

Comment: Even better to have both, so that one may learn what it is without having to download a pdf.